# IF statement won't take more than 2 conditions

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm setting up a system where if a users group number is present the user will have access to the page. For example I want people in group 7,8, and 14 to have access to the page. This works fine for the users in group 7 and 8 but if the user is group 14 access appears to be denied. Here's what I tried so far I tried to go this two ways but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

An if statment with more than two conditions.

```
if ($_SESSION['userrole'] == 8 || $_SESSION['userrole']== 7 || $_SESSION['userrole']== 14) {
//text 
}else{
echo "access denied";
```

An array that have values to check against

```
$acc = array("8","7","14");
    if (in_array($_SESSION['userrole'],$acc)){
//text 
}else{
echo "access denied";
```

Comment: Both methods should work. There's no limit on the number of conditions you can have in the `if`.

Comment: Add the output of `var_dump($_SESSION['userrole'])` when it doesn't work.

Comment: This user is a member of group 2 and 14
Permission Denied!
string(4) "2,14"

Comment: `$_SESSION['userrole']` should look like `array(2,14)` not a string (`"2,14"`). Check how you store the data, or use explode().

Comment: Why would you expect that to work? `"14" != "2,14"` @David

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify the problem. Your code is written correctly if `$_SESSION['userrole']` is just a single role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Syscall mentioned in his comment you are trying to look for the value  **"2,14"**
in array contain values like this **array("8","7","14");**
this is want work

what you need to do in this case is use **explode()**

in your scenario, it will look like this

```
$acc = array("8", "7", "14");
$user_group = explode(',',$_SESSION['userrole']);
foreach ($user_group as $group) {
    if (in_array($group, $acc)) {
       //text
    } else {
       //text
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `$user_group_arr`?

Comment: You can just use `array_intersect($acc, $user_group_arr)`

Comment: I edit it sorry for that

Comment: The `explode()` call is missing from your code snippet.